# Python Apache Beam convert list of dicts to multiple PCollection elements

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

As part of my dataflow I have a `CombineFn` that returns a list of dicts. I want to print each dict to an avro file as a record. However, when I apply `beam.io.WriteToAvro` to my `CombineFn` output, it fails.

It seems like the full list of dicts is being treated as a single element. Is there any way I can get it to treat it like a list of elements?

Comment: Would be useful to see the code for your CombineFn, what is it combining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully there's a better way to do this, but I was able to break the list up by applying the following `DoFn`:

```
class BreakList(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        for e in element:
            yield e
```

Comment: This works but I wonder if using a `CombineFn` in the first place is the right choice given the combined (list of dict) element output is not what you wanted. Combining then de-combining seems like unecessary work, but without seeing the code I could be wrong. If the combined `list of dicts` is unavoidable, then perhaps a `FlatMap` would work. Turn your `CombineFn` code into a function (that still returns the same list of dicts) and pass that function in to `beam.FlatMap`, which will turn your _PCollection of list of dicts_ into a _PCollection of dicts_